# How Can I Use Custom HtmlHelper With IEnumerable page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper

My view page like this;

```
@model IEnumerable<Project.ViewModels.ViewModel>
@using Helpers

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    @Html.MyCustomHtmlHelper("test")
}
```

My custom HtmlHelper like this;

```
public static MvcHtmlString MyCustomHtmlHelper(this HtmlHelper helper, string TestValue)
{
    var builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.Append(TestValue);

    return MvcHtmlString.Create(builder.ToString());
}
```

It works with `@model Project.ViewModels.ViewModel` but not `@model IEnumerable<Project.ViewModels.ViewModel>`

My error;

[image]

Comment: I changed my question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have shown in your question:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    @Html.MyCustomHtmlHelper("test")
}
```

doesn't correspond to the code shown in the YSOD:

```
<td>
    @Html.MyCustomHtmlHelper(TestValue)
</td>
```

It looks like in your real code (which you haven't shown us), you have used some `TestValue` variable. Unfortunately it's pretty hard to know how/where/of what type is this variable declared but if it is not a `string` it is more than obvious that your custom helper won't work for the simple reason that this helper expects a string parameter.

Comment: Your answer is not directly my answer but it helps me to find my solve..
I try to give nullable value.. it is the problem..
Thank you again Darin Dimitrov

Comment: Well, I hope you realize I cannot know the direct answer because I don't know what code you have written because the code you have shown in your question is different than your actual code.

Comment: Yes yes :) I try to generalize my problem because normally questions are complicated..